# Secure XMPP on Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, encryption, xmpp, end-to-end

Does anyone know if its possible to have end-to-end encryption on xmpp messages from the google app engine, like you can with google talk?

Comment: you may need to specify what you mean by end to end encryption. You can encrypt the messages in xmpp, and decrypt it in the application layer, if I understand what is meant by end to end.

Comment: i'm not really sure what i ment by end to end, but that is what google called it for google talk, i think. I just need the communications between the app and the client program to be secure.

Comment: You mean like using https...?

Comment: yep, i used that for the website part

Answer (score 2):

this is built in automatically. xmpp messages between users and app engine apps are encrypted exactly the same way as messages between users themselves. specifically, user clients and app engine apps both connect to the google talk server over SSL/TLS.

if you want true [end to end encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_encryption), that's much harder and much more work. you can do it, e.g. with [OTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-the-Record_Messaging) or something similar, but it's overkill for most use cases.